# How to provide a messageConverterClass to http source

Tags: spring-xd

What is the best way to publish a class that can be used as messageConverterClass in http source?
I have implemented one but I am not able to let the http source see the class. I get ClassNotFoundException.
I had a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#How-to-Add-a-Spring-Bean-to-the-XD-Container) and changed the servers.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a jar containing the class to the source's `/lib` directory or to `xd/lib`.